# Глобальный хук на вызов функции из библиотеки

Tags: c++, winapi

Необходимо отслеживать вызов функции из системной dll. Прошу помощи с этим вопросом. В интернете одни хуки на клавиатуру. будет круто, если есть пример, заранее спасибо!

Comment: @nick_n_a хорошо, а есть, может быть идея, как тогда можно по-другому отловить вызов функции из библиотеки wbemcli.h? или хотя бы получить уведомление о том, что библиотека где-то начала использоваться. Например таким-то процессом...

Comment: @nick_n_a wbemuuid.lib - ей принадлежит хидер

Comment: Нет, lib не перехватывается. lib это промежуточный код который не участвует при работе программ. Перехватывается dll или exe.

Comment: @nick_n_a  хорошо, понял. А как тогда перехватить использование WMI API?

Comment: 1. Находите нужную функцию. 2. Находите в какой именно она dll. 3. Читаете осваиваете инжекцию.

Comment: Если ф-ция виндовая, узнать dll проще.  Как имя вашей функции? Пишите в гугле msdn OpenFileA, открываем ссылку, Library  Kernel32.lib,  DLL  Kernel32.dll - вот это оно.

Answer (score 1):

Глобальный хук на АПИ возможен только из под уровня драйвера:

1. Во первых это тонна кода (и вряд ли возникнет желание безвозмездно поделится потому что не легко такой написать).
2. Не каждый умеет собрать драйвер.
3. К-во платформ которые охватит драйвер ограничено, придётся мучатся что бы работало под разными платформами, или писать несколько драйверов под каждую из платформ.
4. Такой код в свободном доступе может увеличить количество троянов или может быть использован во вред.
5. Не подписанный драйвер - будет везде писать что он не подписанный. Можно даже запретить не подписанные драйверы на компе. Подпись - затрудняюсь ответить насколько дорого и сколько надо делать движений что бы её получить.

Хук на клавиатуру - это немножко другое - такой хук предусмотрен самой системой. А на АПИ - нет. Не путайте хук клавиатуры и хук dll. Есть функция `SetWindowsHookEx` которая позволяет ставить хуки на несколько механизмов взаимодействия с пользователем, но меню перехватов довольно ограничено.

Существуют упрощённые методы, например "инъекция DLL". Смотрите примеры инжекции. Осваивайте, может быть получится. Требуются админские привилегий если процесс чужой, если процесс свой - не требуются. Хук получится - локальный. Инжекция возможна если:

1. захватываемый процесс приложение (перехват службы наверно не выйдет)
2. совпадает разрядность (x86 программа не захватит x64, наоборот возможно что-то получится). И кажется всё. Это не 100%-ный захват. И для новичка довольно трудная задача. Качественный пример инжекции с всеми особенностями не могу показать.